# Resolve is not defined, using non inline function as callback nodejs promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I want to create a generic callback function that all my REST functions can use, in this case, it is called defaultCallback and is defined below. The issue is, that I am getting a "resolve is not defined" error when I hit it. Is this paradigm of using an non inline defined function as a callback possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong? Heres my code

```
function getUsingRest() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
      request({
      url: url,
      headers: headers
    }, function(error, response) {
          defaultCallback(error, response);
      });
    });
  }

  function defaultCallback(error, response) {
    if(error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
      }
  }
```

Comment: it's not in scope ... guess you could do [this](https://pastebin.com/xVAXF2YL)

Comment: how do I make it in scope? Pass the resolve and reject to the default callback too?

Comment: The function scope is not the same of the promise one, so `resolve` and `reject` won't exist in `defaultCallback`. Either follow a different approach (like not calling the function at all and put the code directly inline), either pass a resolve and reject reference to the defaultCallback (as function arguments), either hack with `.call` or `.apply`,  but that would be awful.

Comment: you could, or you could write the code like in the patebin I linked to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to declare `defaultCallback` inside the `new Promise` constructor to have the `resolve` and `reject` variables in scope. Just drop that "default callback" and write

```
function getUsingRest() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
    request({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
    }
  });
}
```

or better

```
function getUsingRest() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    request({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(response);
    }
  }).then(response => JSON.parse(response.body));
}
```

so that exceptions from `JSON.parse` are caught and lead to a promise rejection.

If you insist on making that "default" promise callback generic so that you can share it between multiple functions, have a look at [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) (and its implementation, in case you are interested).

Answer (score -1):

Not need to wrap `defaultCallback` by anonymous function
Try to change

```
 request(json, function(error, response) {
      defaultCallback(error, response);
  });
```

to

```
request(json, defaultCallback);
```